# two column layout widget broken

Tags: apostrophe-cms

**Hi,**

I am following this tutorial :
https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/layout-widgets.html

here is my code:
https://github.com/daslicht/apostrope-starter/blob/master/lib/modules/two-column-widgets/index.js

––– –– –

**Result:**

[image]

––– –– –

I don't get any error in the console, 
how to debug such things ?
Whats is wrong, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` property of an area must be a dot notation-valid name, `twoColumnLayout` instead of `two-column-layout`.

in your `home.html` change the area call to look like

```
{{
  apos.area(data.page, 'twoColumnLayout', {
    widgets: {
      'two-column': {}
    }
  })
}}
```

From MDN on valid JavaScript identifier naming

> ... a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore
>   ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors